# Gathering the date and plotting the process in GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a dataset that contains 25 variables and 112095 observations.

I am trying to plot a graph with 5 variables.

[image: Sample dataset]

In the image, you could see that I am having date in 1 column, process types in column 2, column 4 with upper-limit and column 3 with lower limit, column 5 with measured value.

I would like to plot the measured value with respect to each process and draw the upper limit and lower limit in the line. in the sample data set i have shown only 3 process, but in reality i have 14 process and i want to display them on a single panel.
below is the sample image,

[image: Sample image]
Could anyone, help me how i could start with this ? I am new with R and ggplot.

EDIT:
for 1 process, here is the sample graph, it should look like

[image: Expected output]

For eg from the graph, it is for 1 process, that the points inside with different colors are measure values, with the green line on the top and below as Lower and upper bound,and the different colored points indicate the different days(thur,fri, sat).

Comment: Hi, for your scatter plot, could you clarifying what you want as the x and y axis?

Comment: @whalea I have added a Edit for one process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some random data

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2018-05-04", "2018-05-06", "2018-09-04", "2018-09-07")),
                 process = c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P2"),
                 lower_bound = c(0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5),
                 upper_bound = c(2.5, 2.5, 3.7, 3.7),
                 mv = c(1, 2, 3, 3.2)) %>%
  mutate(wd = wday(date))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = wd, y = mv, col = as.factor(wd)), width = 0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = wd, y = lower_bound), colour = 'green') +
  geom_line(aes(x = wd, y = upper_bound), colour = 'green') +
  facet_wrap(~process, ncol = 3)
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: If i am not wrong, i could see that you have assigned the y axis with upper bound and lower bound value ?

Comment: also i am getting a warning message (pango-warning: invalid UTF 8 string passed to pango_layout

Comment: it is not assigning the y-axis, but plotting a line and using the upper and lower bounds as the y-values. for the pango-warning, it could be related to your environment set up...

Comment: also when i use mutate, I am getting an error   Column `day` must be length 0 (the number of rows) or one, not 119195

Comment: the lines plotted are not evident, could you tell me how i could change those colurs

Comment: I believe for the `mutate` error, you are missing the `%>%` pipe, if you are not familiar with piping, you should be doing `mutate(df, wd = wday(date))`. For colours, you can use `geom_line(colour = 'green')`. For more on controlling colours in `ggplot`, see http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html

Comment: Yeah, i rectified the error. Just the plotting my upper bound line and lowerbound line i could not. I want something like in the image i showed you

Comment: I have updated the code above, the data and the expected plot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168739/discussion-between-jenny-and-whalea).